# how to add images for buttons in visual studio 2005 with windows CE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I have created user control using visual studio 2005 c# with windows CE device, in that I am using button, how to set background image for that button.
BackgroundImage property is not available in Windows CE device.

If any one find th solution please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446518.aspx).